# SSH sequre shell sql code...?

Tags: mysql

I'm really frusterated with these codes and I can't find where the errors are..

SSH secure shell .txt file with the error codes:

```css
Table created.

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
  2   OrderID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  3   OrderDate      DATE       NOT NULL,
  4   CustID      CHAR(5)       NOT NULL,
  5   PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID),
  6   FOREIGN KEY    (CustID)      REFERENCES Customer_mys
  7   ) ;
CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE Product_mys (
  2   ProductID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  3   ProductName    VARCHAR(30)      NOT NULL,
  4   CatID      Number(3)       NOT NULL,
  5   PRIMARY KEY    (ProductID),
  6   FOREIGN KEY    (CatID)      REFERENCES Category_mys
  7   ) ;
CREATE TABLE Product_mys (
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> 
SQL> CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
  2   OrderID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  3   ProductID      NUMBER(3)       NOT NULL,
  4   ProductQty     NUMBER(4)       NOT NULL,
  5   ProdcutPrice   NUMBER(6,2)      NOT NULL,
  6   PRIMARY KEY    (OrderID, ProductID),
  7   FOREIGN KEY    (OrderID)      REFERENCES Order_mys,
  8   FOREIGN KEY    (ProductID)     REFERENCES Product_mys
  9   ) ;
CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
             *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object 


SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> DESCRIBE Dept_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 DEPTID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 DEPTNAME                                  NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> DESCRIBE Commission_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COMMCLASS                                 NOT NULL CHAR(1)
 COMMRATE                                  NOT NULL NUMBER(2,2)

SQL> DESCRIBE Category_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CATID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 CATNAME                                   NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)

SQL> DESCRIBE SalesRep_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 SALESREPID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 SALESREPFNAME                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 SALESREPLNAME                             NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 DEPTID                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 COMMCLASS                                 NOT NULL CHAR(1)

SQL> DESCRIBE Customer_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 CUSTID                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)
 CUSTFNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 CUSTLNAME                                 NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
 CUSTPHONE                                          CHAR(10)
 SALESREPID                                NOT NULL NUMBER(4)

SQL> DESCRIBE Order_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ORDERID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 ORDERDATE                                 NOT NULL DATE
 CUSTID                                    NOT NULL CHAR(5)

SQL> DESCRIBE Product_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 PRODUCTID                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 PRODUCTNAME                               NOT NULL VARCHAR2(30)
 CATID                                     NOT NULL NUMBER(3)

SQL> DESCRIBE OrderDetail_mys ;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ORDERID                                   NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 PRODUCTID                                 NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
 PRODUCTQTY                                NOT NULL NUMBER(4)
 PRODCUTPRICE                              NOT NULL NUMBER(6,2)

SQL> 
SQL> --Part II
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Dept_mys
  2  VALUES (10, 'Store Sales') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Dept_mys
  2  VALUES (14, 'Corp Sales') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Dept_mys
  2  VALUES (16, 'Web Sales') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Commission_mys
  2  VALUES (A, .1) ;
VALUES (A, .1) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Commission_mys
  2  VALUES (B, .08) ;
VALUES (B, .08) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Commission_mys
  2  VALUES (Z, 0) ;
VALUES (Z, 0) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Commission_mys
  2  VALUES (C, .05) ;
VALUES (C, .05) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (1, 'Hand Tools') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (2, 'power Tools') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (4, 'Fasteners') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (6, 'Misc') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (3, 'Measuring Tools') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Category_mys
  2  VALUES (5, 'Hardware') ;

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (10, 'Alice', 'Jones', 10, 'A') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (12, 'Greg', 'Taylor', 14, 'B') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (14, 'Sara', 'Day', 10, 'Z') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (8, 'Kay', 'Price', 14, 'C') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (20, 'Bob', 'Jackson', 10, 'B') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
  2  VALUES (22, 'Micah', 'Moore', 16, 'Z') ;
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MYS2306.SYS_C00966867) violated - parent key 
not found 


SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Customer_mys
  2  VALUES (S100, 'John', 'Smith', '5551212', 10) ;
VALUES (S100, 'John', 'Smith', '5551212', 10) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Customer_mys
  2  VALUES (A120, 'Jane', 'Adams', '817555', 14) ;
VALUES (A120, 'Jane', 'Adams', '817555', 14) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Customer_mys
  2  VALUES (J090, 'Tim', 'Jones', NULL, 10) ;
VALUES (J090, 'Tim', 'Jones', NULL, 10) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here 


SQL> 
SQL> INSERT INTO Customer_mys
  2  VALUES (B200, 'Ann', 'Brown', '972555', 14) ;
VALUES (B200, 'Ann', 'Brown', '972555', 14) 
        *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Here's the tables that I did with the relationships, foreign key, inserts

```css
DROP TABLE Customer_mys ;
DROP TABLE SalesRep_mys ;
DROP TABLE Category_mys ;
DROP TABLE Commission_mys ;
DROP TABLE Dept_mys ;

--part I

 CREATE TABLE Dept_mys (
 DeptID  Number(3)  NOT NULL,
 DeptName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (DeptID) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Commission_mys (
 CommClass CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
 CommRate Number(2,2)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (CommClass) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Category_mys (
 CatID  Number(3)  NOT NULL,
 catName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (CatID) 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE SalesRep_mys (
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 SalesRepFName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 SalesRepLName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 DeptID  NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 CommClass CHAR(1)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (SalesRepID),
 FOREIGN KEY (DeptID)  REFERENCES Dept_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY (CommClass) REFERENCES Commission_mys 
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Customer_mys (
 CustID  VARCHAR(5)  NOT NULL,
 CustFName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 CustLName VARCHAR(20)  NOT NULL,
 CustPhone CHAR(10),
 SalesRepID NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (CustID),
 FOREIGN KEY (SalesRepID) REFERENCES Customer_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Order_mys (
 OrderID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 OrderDate DATE   NOT NULL,
 CustID  CHAR(5)   NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID),
 FOREIGN KEY (CustID) REFERENCES Customer_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE Product_mys (
 ProductID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductName VARCHAR(30)  NOT NULL,
 CatID  Number(3)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY (CatID)  REFERENCES Category_mys
 ) ;

CREATE TABLE OrderDetail_mys (
 OrderID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductID NUMBER(3)  NOT NULL,
 ProductQty NUMBER(4)  NOT NULL,
 ProdcutPrice NUMBER(6,2)  NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (OrderID, ProductID),
 FOREIGN KEY (OrderID)  REFERENCES Order_mys,
 FOREIGN KEY (ProductID)  REFERENCES Product_mys
 ) ;


DESCRIBE Dept_mys ;
DESCRIBE Commission_mys ;
DESCRIBE Category_mys ;
DESCRIBE SalesRep_mys ; 
DESCRIBE Customer_mys ;
DESCRIBE Order_mys ;
DESCRIBE Product_mys ;
DESCRIBE OrderDetail_mys ;

--Part II

INSERT INTO Dept_mys
VALUES (10, 'Store Sales') ;

INSERT INTO Dept_mys
VALUES (14, 'Corp Sales') ;

INSERT INTO Dept_mys
VALUES (16, 'Web Sales') ;



INSERT INTO Commission_mys
VALUES (A, .1) ; 

INSERT INTO Commission_mys
VALUES (B, .08) ;

INSERT INTO Commission_mys
VALUES (Z, 0) ;

INSERT INTO Commission_mys
VALUES (C, .05) ;


INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (1, 'Hand Tools') ;

INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (2, 'power Tools') ;

INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (4, 'Fasteners') ;

INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (6, 'Misc') ;

INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (3, 'Measuring Tools') ;

INSERT INTO Category_mys
VALUES (5, 'Hardware') ;



INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (10, 'Alice', 'Jones', 10, A) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (12, 'Greg', 'Taylor', 14, B) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (14, 'Sara', 'Day', 10, Z) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (8, 'Kay', 'Price', 14, C) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (20, 'Bob', 'Jackson', 10, B) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (22, 'Micah', 'Moore', 16, Z) ;



INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (S100, 'John', 'Smith', '5551212', 10) ;

INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (A120, 'Jane', 'Adams', '817555', 14) ;

INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (J090, 'Tim', 'Jones', NULL, 10) ;

INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (B200, 'Ann', 'Brown', '972555', 14) ;

INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (G070, 'Kate', 'Green', NULL, 10) ;

INSERT INTO Customer_mys
VALUES (S120, 'Nicole', 'Sims', NULL, 16) ;


INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (100, '24-Jan-15', S100) ;

INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (101, '25-Jan-15', A120) ;

INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (102, '26-Jan-15', J090) ;

INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (105, '26-Jan-15', B200) ;

INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (106, '27-Jan-15', G070) ;

INSERT INTO Order_mys
VALUES (108, '27-Jan-15', S120) ;


INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (121, 'BD Hammer', 1) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (228, 'Makita Power Drill', 2) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (480, '1 # BD Nails', 4) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (610, '3M Duct Tape', 6) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (618, '3M Masking Tape', 6) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (380, 'Acme Yard Stick', 3) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (535, 'Schlage Door Knob', 5) ;     

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (123, 'Acme Pry Bar', 1) ; 

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (229, 'BD Power Drill', 2) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (124, 'Acme Hammer', 1) ;  

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (235, 'Makita Power Drill', 2) ;



INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (100, 121, 2, 8.00) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (100, 228, 2, 65.00) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (100, 480, 2, 3.00) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (100, 407, 1, 4.25) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (101, 610, 200, 1.75) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (101, 618, 100, 1.25) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (101, 121, 2, 8.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (102, 380, 2, 1.25) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (102, 121, 1, 7.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (102, 535, 4, 7.50) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (103, 121, 50, 7.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (103, 123, 20, 6.25) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (101, 121, 2, 8.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (104, 229, 1, 50.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (104, 610, 200, 1.75) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (104, 380, 2, 1.25) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (104, 535, 4, 7.50) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (101, 121, 2, 8.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (105, 610, 200, 1.75) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (105, 123, 40, 5.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (106, 124, 1, 6.50) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (107, 229, 1, 59.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (108, 235, 1, 65.00) ;


COMMIT ;



SELECT * FROM Dept_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Commission_mys ;
SELECT * FROM SalesRep_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Customer_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Category_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Order_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Product_mys ;
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail_mys ; 


--PART III


UPDATE Customer_mys
   SET CustLName = 'Thompson'
 WHERE CustID = 'A120' ;


UPDATE Customer_mys
   SET CustPhone = '2146881234'
 WHERE CustID = 'J090' ;   


UPDATE Product_mys
  SET ProductPrice = 7.50 
WHERE ProductID = '121' ;

UPDATE OrderDetail_mys
  SET ProductName = 'BD Claw Hammer' ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys 
VALUES (122, 'BD Rubber Mallet', 1) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (125, 'Stanley Chisel', 1) ; 

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (126, 'BD Chisel', 1) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (381, 'BD Measuring Tape', 3) ;

INSERT INTO Product_mys
VALUES (382, 'Stanley Meausring Tape', 3) ; 

INSERT INTO Commission_mys
VALUES (D, .03) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (21, 'Mark', 'Anderson', 14, C) ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (23, 'Jennie', 'Hayes', 10, D) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (109, 228, 1, 62.50) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (109, 407, 1, 4.00) ;

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (109, 381, 2, 7.75) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (110, 122, 2, 7.00) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (110, 124, 1, 6.75) ; 

INSERT INTO OrderDetail_mys
VALUES (110, 480, 2, 3.25) ; 


COMMIT ; 
SELECT * FROM Dept_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Commission_mys ;
SELECT * FROM SalesRep_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Customer_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Category_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Order_mys ;
SELECT * FROM Product_mys ;
SELECT * FROM OrderDetail_mys ;
```

Comment: It would be good if you debug this more yourself instead of just dropping a whole script here. You will get faster an answer... Already the first error in your script is pretty clear in terms of what it says: "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object". Extract the errors and try to make your question more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're getting this error because A and B are being interpreted as some kind of variable. Try modifying your query to

```
INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys 
VALUES (10, 'Alice', 'Jones', 10, 'A') ;

INSERT INTO SalesRep_mys
VALUES (12, 'Greg', 'Taylor', 14, 'B') ;
```

Comment: So the commClass are put in single quotes..? Will try and see! Thanks mate!

Comment: yup! Because they're CHARs

Comment: I'm getting more error codes. I will edit the question and add the whole tables and schemas. I hope you can help me out with it. I would definitely choose your answer